# Python - gap on exit sequence,error on comparing decimal

Tags: python

I enter with numbers out of sequence, subtract the repeated ones, maintaining the order, subtract`[']"`of list on exit (is there any more pythonic way for this?). I do not know where I'm going wrong, it fails to compare units of the dozen and a space appears on the output.

`a = 1 1 4 4 4 8 8 2 14 14 11 11`

expected exit `b = 1 4 8 2 14 11`

wrong output
`b = 1   4 8 2`

```
def repeated(s):
    t = []
    [t.append(item) for item in s if not t.count(item)]
    return t

def remove(s,to_remove):
    for x in to_remove:
        s = s.replace(x, '')
    return s

def main():
    a = input('a = ')
    print('b = ', (remove(str(repeated(a)), "['],")))

main()
exit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

more better use sets

```
a = set(input().split()) 
print(' '.join(a))
```

sets can be contains only unique values, and you don't need to remove values. All values will be unique by default.

Comment: thank you very much for your attention !! I'm newbie, but I'm going to learn.